# How to stop a looping animation in React Native?

Tags: javascript, animation, react-native

I have a simple looping animation in my component like this:

```
runAnimation() {
    console.log('run animation');
    this.state.angle.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(this.state.angle, {
        toValue: 360,
        duration: 8000,
        easing: Easing.linear
    }).start(() => this.runAnimation());
}

...

<Animated.Image
    style={[
        styles.rotate,
        { transform: [
            { rotate: this.state.angle.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 360],
                outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
            })},
        ]}
    ]}
    source={require('./spinning_ball.png')}
/>
```

How would I stop this animation? For example, when navigating away to another screen or after a user clicks on a button.

I tried using **this.state.angle.stopAnimation()** but noticed *run animation* still being printed in the console. Is there a different stop method I should be calling to prevent the start callback from being executed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on my comment in Nguyên Hoàng's answer. Here is another way to stop the looping animation if you call `this.state.angle.stopAnimation()`:

```
runAnimation() {
  this.state.angle.setValue(0);
  Animated.timing(this.state.angle, {
    toValue: 360,
    duration: 8000,
    easing: Easing.linear
  }).start((o) => {
    if(o.finished) {
      this.runAnimation();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Both solutions worked, but this seemed like a much cleaner implementation.

Comment: Nice catch o.finished

Answer (score 11):

I like to encapsulate my animations in hooks, it makes for a much cleaner, easier, and more reusable pattern than class components. Here's how I do a looping animation with easy start/stop control in typescript:

```
export const useBounceRotateAnimation = (running: boolean = true, rate: number = 300) => {
    //Example of making an infinite looping animation and controlling it with a boolean
    //Note that this assumes the "rate" is constant -- if you wanted to change the rate value after creation the implementation would have to change a bit

    //Only create the animated value once
    const val = useRef(new Animated.Value(0))

    //Store a reference to the animation since we're starting-stopping an infinite loop instead of starting new animations and we aren't changing any animation values after creation. We only want to create the animation object once.
    const anim = useRef(
        Animated.loop(
            Animated.timing(val.current, {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: rate,
                easing: Easing.linear,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                isInteraction: false,
            })
        )
    ).current

    //Interpolate the value(s) to whatever is appropriate for your case
    const interpolatedY = val.current.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
        outputRange: [0, 6, 0],
    })
    const interpolatedRotate = val.current.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 0.25, 0.5, 1],
        outputRange: ["0deg", "-3deg", "3deg", "0deg"],
    })

    //Start and stop the animation based on the value of the boolean prop
    useEffect(() => {
        if (running) {
            anim.start()
        } else {
            //When stopping reset the value to 0 so animated item doesn't stop in a random position
            anim.stop()
            val.current.setValue(0)
        }

        //Return a function from useEffect to stop the animation on unmount
        return () => anim.stop()
     //This useEffect should rerun if "running" or "anim" changes (but anim won't change since its a ref we never modify)
    }, [running, anim])

     //Return the animated values. Use "as const" const assertion to narrow the output type to exactly the two values being returned. 
    return [interpolatedY, interpolatedRotate] as const
}
```

I use this actual hook implementation to make a character image "walk" in my game. Now in my component it's very easy to use:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(true)

    const [translation, rotation] = useBounceRotateAnimation(isRunning)

    return (
        <Animated.View
            style={{
                transform: [{ translateY: translation}, { rotate: rotation}],
            }}
        >
             ....rest of your component here, just setIsRunning(false) to stop animation whenever you need
        </Animated.View>
    )
}
```

As you can see this pattern is very clean and reusable. The animated component doesn't need to know anything about the animation, it just consumes the animated values and tells the animation when to run.

Comment: I've found this approach really worked for me, thanks! In my case, I wanted to stop the animation upon leaving a page, and restart the whole thing when re-entering the same page, and found I also needed to call `anim.reset()` in the returned ('unmounting') function

Answer (score 5):

You can create a variable `stopAnimation` to stop Animation whenever you want by only when `stopAnimation === false` then callback `runAnimation` function. Like example:

```
this.state = { stopAnimation: false }

runAnimation() {
  this.state.spinValue.setValue(0);
  Animated.timing(
    this.state.spinValue,
    {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 3000,
      easing: Easing.linear
    }
  ).start( () => {
    if(this.state.stopAnimation === false) {
      this.runAnimation();
    }
  });
}
```

So you just need to create a button which call function `this.state = { stopAnimation: true }` to stop Animation.

Example here: https://rnplay.org/apps/Lpmh8A.

Comment: Is this the only way to do this? I had already considered this as a possibility, but it doesn't feel like cleanest approach. I'm also wondering if someone could explain why stopAnimation() triggers the callback when the animation technically didn't finish. Or does it? Doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: where is the place u call `this.state.angle.stopAnimation()` @MichaelCheng

Comment: @MichaelCheng The callback in `start()` will be invoked regardless. If it finishes normally, you will get an object of `{finished: true}` in the callback. But if it is interrupted (e.g. by `stopAnimation()`), you will get `{finished: false}` instead in the callback.

Comment: @NguyênHoàng I was trying it out in componentWillUnmount and componentDidUnmount.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the loop using:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
   Animated.timing(this.state.angle).stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to stop looping animation by calling `setValue()` method and assign a value. like:

```
const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(new Animated.value(0));

// declare your looping animated function

// Any time to stop the looping animated function just call setValue() 
// on your stop animation event or function using opcacity reference. like
opacity.setValue(0)
```

For more details https://reactnative.dev/docs/animatedvaluexy#setvalue

Answer (score 0):

**Set a global variable**

```ts
let dataloaded = false;
```

**To stop animation override the variable (dataloaded) whenever you want**

```ts
componentWillUnmount() {
    dataloaded = true;
}

onPress={() => {
    dataloaded = true;
}}
```

final code will look like

```ts
runAnimation() {
    console.log('run animation');
    this.state.angle.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(this.state.angle, {
        toValue: 360,
        duration: 8000,
        easing: Easing.linear
    })
    .start(() => {
        if ( ! dataloaded) {
            this.runAnimation();
        }
    })
}
```