# react native animated repeat infinity

Tags: react-native

I have the following animation.

```
  componentWillMount(){
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(300);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    Animated.timing( this.animatedValue , {
      toValue: -100,
      duration: 3000,

    } ).start();
  }

  render() {
    const animatedStyle = { marginLeft: this.animatedValue, marginRight: - this.animatedValue };

    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', height: 100,}}>
        <Animated.View style={[ animatedStyle,{backgroundColor: 'blue', width:100}]} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I would like to repeat endless times. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass a callback to `Animated.start()` that resets the Animated value and starts the animation again. For example:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.runAnimation();
}

runAnimation() {
  this.animatedValue.setValue(300);
  Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
    toValue: -100,
    duration: 3000,
  }).start(() => this.runAnimation());
}
```

If you need to stop the animation at any point, take a look at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149793/how-to-stop-a-looping-animation-in-react-native).

Comment: That's what I need. Thanks

Comment: Is this will not exceed the call stack?? it looks like a recursive function without any condition?

Answer (score 35):

2019 solution:

```
Animated.loop(Animated.timing(this.animatedValue , {
    toValue: -100,
    duration: 3000,
})).start();
```